# What is Ansible syntax to dereference PowerShell get-NetAdapter output?

Tags: ansible-2.x

Consider the following from a Powershell session on a WS2019 instance, ...

```
  PS> get-netadapter -Name "*" -physical

      Name                 InterfaceDescription             ifIndex Status  ...
      ----                 --------------------             --------------  ...
      Ethernet0 2          vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter         3 up            ...
```

I want to use the above **Name** value as a *conditional* in an *Ansible Play*, so i *task* ...

```
  - name: Get current NIC name (re-entrant flag)
      ansible.windows.win_powershell:
        script: |
          Get-NetAdapter -Name "*" -physical
      register: NIC
```

... and then use **NIC.Name** in a later conditional; but it fails as *undefined*.  So, i debug *NIC* to learn structure and get this huge enumeration that includes the following (i deleted some irrelevant rows for purpose of this post) ...

```
    "NIC: {'changed': True, 'result': {}, 'host_out': '', 'host_err': '', 'output': [{'PowerOnHours':None, 'Virtual': False, 'ReceiveLinkSpeed': 10000000000, 'ElementName': None, ...
\Device\\\\{2C89B206-627B-45C0-B9F9-AFAEDA168DF6}', 'Name': 'Ethernet0 2', 'PSComputerName': None, ...
'PortNumber': 0, 'OtherPortType': None}], 'error': [], 'warning': [], 'verbose': [], 'debug': [], 'information': [], 'failed': False}",
```

In attempting to find a working hierarchy/syntax, i debugged for the following with the results as commented ...

```
 - name: Debug essentials 
      debug:
        msg:
          - "NIC: {{ NIC }}"
          #has no attribute - "NIC Name: {{ NIC.Name }}"
          - "NIC output: {{ NIC.output }}"
          #wtf; this task won't run with this line: - "NIC output name: {{ NIC.output.name }}"
          #has no attribute - "NIC output Name: {{ NIC.output.Name }}"
          #has no attribute - "NIC output PowerOnHours: {{ NIC.output.PowerOnHours }}"
          #has no attribute - "NIC output CIM: {{ NIC.output.CimInstanceProperties }}"
          - "Survey Network Name: {{ VMNetwork  }}"
```

That is, only **NIC** and **NIC.output** statements of the above were valid.  Can anyone help me to learn ...

NIC<***missing syntax***>Name

... such that i can use it in a later play as a conditional argument.

Summary: I intuitively tried ...

NIC.Name

... but it resolves as undefined attribute.  I assessed NIC output via debug and then tried ...

NIC.output.Name

... but got the same undefined results.

Answer (score 0):

I researched *PowerShell* usage of brackets and braces while considering the Name: ***Ethernet0 2***.  My resolve was to try …

```
NIC.output[0].Name
```

... and this worked.  Fortunately, there is only 1 physical NIC on these newly instantiated VMs so it was easy to deduce 0 as the ordinal offset.  If there were more physical NICs, i'd have to learn some more WMI stuff :( ...